# Servlet for full duplex over http, in Java ?

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, servlets

Is it possible to write a servlet which would both let the client continuously send data, and answer to this as it sees fit?

I tried, but had the following problems:

- requests where only received by servlet input stream when a CR/LF was sent
- it only worked when specifying a content-length (which I don't know beforehand)
- response was only sent to client after the request was complete (I'd like to have both streams running independently); note: I'm fully confident about my threading code

Is it possible?

Comment: ANYTHING IS POSSIBLE WITH ENOUGH COFFE

Comment: On a serious note - what do you have so far? This is a little general..

Comment: @Adel Wrote a servlet which echoes request to response, and a couple of others. The echo servlet seems to be the best tool so far.

Comment: @Adel I want it to display "x" when I hit "x" (from putty or custom client), and then "y" if I press "y" after that, and so on. It nows display "x" if I write "x"+ENTER, and I specified a content-length, and stops after that.

Comment: Use http 1.1 & chunked transfers for both client & server. What comes to crlf, are you sure it's not the client that is causing the delay?

Comment: @SamiKorhonen I tried with putty (raw mode), and an hand-coded client (simply writing to socket).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to write a servlet which would both let the client continuously send data, and answer to this as it sees fit?

[update]

Perhaps you are looking for something like [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)  (which I have not used yet so I'm not going to be much help there).

I am currently sticking with a comet approach to solve similar problems - the idea is that you have a queue of outgoing messages somewhere and do long polling to read these messages as they become available.  It avoids some of the problems you have encountered, for example, Content-Length is known before hand because you don't try to pull information until you have some type of complete, application-specific message.

[original]

Yes.  The buzzword is `comet`.  A quick google of `java comet` returned a link to the following article which may help: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-cometjava/

Comment: Thanks. Still, long polling is essentially what I'm trying to achieve, but I don't see how to solve the 3 problems mentioned in my question. Maybe it's an http question, more than a java one.